# where condition inside nested list linq

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have two classes

```
  public class Item
  {
    public string LineID{ get; set; }
    public string ItemNo{ get; set; }
    public List<Itemcode> ItemcodeList{ get; set; }
  }

  public class Itemcode
   {
      public string LineID{ get; set; }
      public string code { get; set; }
      public string codeValue { get; set; }
   }
```

and two datatables ds.Tables[1] and ds.Tables[2]

I am converting the data from two dataset into list of Item class which also contains List of Itemcode class

What I am doing is as follows

```
 List<Item> items = ds.Tables[1].AsEnumerable().Select(dataRow => new Item
                    {
                        LineID= Convert.ToString(dataRow.Field<int>("LineID")),
                        ItemNo= dataRow.Field<string>("ItemNo"),
                        ItemcodeList = ds.Tables[2].AsEnumerable().Select(row => new Itemcode
                        {
                            code= Convert.ToString(row.Field<string>("code")),
                            codeValue = Convert.ToString(row.Field<string>("codeValue")),
                        }).ToList()
                    }).ToList();
```

The above code gives the all ds.Tables[2] rows against each row of ds.Table[1]

But I want only those rows where LineID of ds.Table[1] match with LineID of ds.Table[2] where I have to change condition

Comment: why do you need AsEnumerable() ?

Comment: becasue DataTable does not implement IEnumerable

Answer (score 3):

IMHO, a cleaner solution (which also improves performance for large data sets) is to first create a lookup of the children, then assemble the parents:

```
        var itemCodes = (
            from dataRow in ds.Tables[2].AsEnumerable()
            select new Itemcode
            {
                LineID = dataRow.Field<string>("LineID"),
                code = dataRow.Field<string>("code"),
                codeValue = dataRow.Field<string>("code")
            }).ToLookup(ic => ic.LineID);

        var lines = (
            from dataRow in ds.Tables[1].AsEnumerable()
            let lineID = dataRow.Field<string>("LineID")
            select new Item
            {
                LineID = lineID,
                ItemNo = dataRow.Field<string>("ItemNo"),
                ItemcodeList = itemCodes[lineID].ToList()
            }).ToList();
```

Or, if you prefer method chain syntax:

```
        var itemCodes = ds.Tables[2].AsEnumerable().Select(dataRow => new Itemcode
        {
            LineID = dataRow.Field<string>("LineID"),
            code = dataRow.Field<string>("code"),
            codeValue = dataRow.Field<string>("code")
        }).ToLookup(ic => ic.LineID);

        var lines = ds.Tables[1].AsEnumerable()
            .Select(dataRow => new {dataRow, lineID = dataRow.Field<string>("LineID")})
            .Select(item => new Item
            {
                LineID = item.lineID,
                ItemNo = item.dataRow.Field<string>("ItemNo"),
                ItemcodeList = itemCodes[item.lineID].ToList()
            }).ToList();
```

Comment: @Silvermind the data is already in memory. And the lookup will only keep references to the objects in its value collection not copies of them.

Answer (score 3):

I think using a [group join](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397905.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) would be a good solution here.

```
var items= (from tbl1 in ds.Tables[1].AsEnumerable()
            join tbl2 in ds.Tables[2].AsEnumerable()
              on tbl1.Field<int>("LineId") equals tbl2.Field<int>("LineID") into g
            select new Item
            {
               LineID = tbl1.Field<int>("LineID").ToString(),
               ItemNo = tbl1.Field<string>("ItemNo"),
               ItemcodeList = g.Select(row => 
                  new Itemcode
                  {
                     code = row.Field<string>("code").ToString(),
                     codeValue = row.Field<string>("codeValue").ToString(),
                  }).ToList()
            }).ToList();
```

Comment: This is indeed the best solution!

Comment: Yep, this is the clearest solution. Just for fun, look at http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,1bdae7e7505451ef. Actually creates a lookup first :-).

Answer (score 0):

Just add where clause and compare it with LineId from datarow

```
List<Item> items = ds.Tables[1].AsEnumerable().Select(dataRow => new Item
                    {
                        LineID= Convert.ToString(dataRow.Field<int>("LineID")),
                        ItemNo= dataRow.Field<string>("ItemNo"),
                        ItemcodeList = ds.Tables[2].AsEnumerable().Where(ic=>ic.Field<int>("LineId")==dataRow.Field<int>("LineID")).Select(row => new Itemcode
                        {
                            code= Convert.ToString(row.Field<string>("code")),
                            codeValue = Convert.ToString(row.Field<string>("codeValue")),
                        }).ToList()
                    }).ToList();
```

**Additional Info**

Here AsEnumerable is different from AsQueryable....Here data is already fetched from your database and is populated in DataTable of your DataSet....Reason you have to do AsEnumerable is because DataTable does not implement **IEnumerable<T>** and all your Linq queries work only on type **IEnumerable<T>**.

Comment: ds.Tables[2].AsEnumerable().Where() - this will fetch ALL the records and apply the condifion afterwards

Comment: you already have records in memory...it is going to enumerate and pick only those which satisfy condition

Comment: @Viru I am getting error System.Data.DataRow' does not contain a definition for 'LineId' and no extension method 'LineId' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Data.DataRow'                 at Where(ic=>ic.LineId==dataRow.Field<int>

Comment: Your solution does not compile. In the 'Where' clause 'ic => ic.LineId', 'ic' is of type 'DataRow' which does not have a property 'LineId'

Answer (score 0):

If you want the *lambda* solution, following should work:

```
List<Item> items =
            ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().GroupJoin(
            ds.Tables[1].AsEnumerable(),
            tab1 => tab1.Field<int>("LineID"),
            tab2 => tab2.Field<int>("LineID"),
            (tab1, tab2) => new Item
                        {
                            LineID = Convert.ToString(tab1.Field<int>("LineID")),
                            ItemNo = tab1.Field<string>("ItemNo"),
                            ItemcodeList = tab2.AsEnumerable().SelectMany(codes=> 
                                new List<Itemcode>                                   
                                {
                                    new Itemcode { code = codes.Field<string>("Code")} 
                                }
                            ).ToList()
                        }
            ).ToList();
```